# Failed Manually Authenticating Users while login

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-authentication

i'm new in laravel. I'm stuck when creating manual authentication with laravel 9.

when the user is successfully logged in, but cannot access the view page with middleware Auth.

I tried dd(Auth::user()) and the result is null.

where is my mistake?

**Controller**
`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class OtorisasiController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('otorisasi.login');
    }


    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validasi = $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt($validasi)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        }

        return back()->with('infologin', 'Data yang anda masukan salah');
    }



    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

`

**route**

`// Deafult Page After Login Route::get('/', [TransfersController::class, 'index'])->name('home')->middleware('auth');`

how to do so, when login is successful, I can access all middleware auth pages

Comment: 1) add users model "class User extends Authenticatable"  2) add trait "use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;"  3) add your controller "  public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }"

Comment: thanks for the help. it turns out that this problem is in the id column that I didn't include in the users table. after i added it all Auth::functions are back to normal